# How can I show “\” (backslash) in button or label text in windows application in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am trying to create keyboard in windows form in vb.net, but I am unable to show "\"(backslash) on button.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You mean in the button text?

Comment: Yes, In the button text.